# ActiveReports : Report gets trimmed on the right

Tags: .net, vb.net, activereports

I have few ActiveReports that I have migrated from Version 2 to Version 16 and generating the reports using VB.Net.
After generating the report, it is getting trimmed towards the right and hence few fields are not appearing on the report.

Comment: Very much a guess as you've given next to no useful information, perhaps the Paper size has been changed from A4 to Letter in the conversion or margins?

Comment: Change the paper orientation and plac margin of 1 cm on Right.keep this thing  in mind that your over all page width must be less than page orientation.